# Is it okay to Post a Website containing Local file addresses in it?

Tags: html, image, url

I'm having a website with images and audios containing in it . The image's and audio's Source is folder wise like

```
<img src="sample.png" />
```

Will it work fine if I post my website and open it in another PC where I don't have that Image

Comment: `Will it work fine if I post my website and open it in another PC where I don't have that Image` Well, no. If you're serving locally and not on the web where the image resides, without the image it will show a broken image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as the same image is in the same place on the other computer / server it will work just fine. if you're unable to have the image on the other computer / server I would recommend uploading it to a service like Imgur and using the image URL instead of the local URL

Answer (score 0):

You should have a folder for saving files such as css, js, images, etc. in your project and put this folder for example on the root folder of your project.

When you want to open your website on another computer you should transfer the whole project containing the folder which I mentioned (with its contents) to the second computer.